# Error setting up Gitolite: Doesn't accept SSH key

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I am trying to setup gitolite on a linux server. When I run the command:

```
gitolite setup -pk id_rsa.pub
```

I get the following error:
FATAL: 'id_rsa.pub' not a readable file

I don't really get what could be wrong ... I generated the keys in openssh format using puttygen. I also tried generating the key through the Git Bash terminal using sshgen -t rsa and I get the same error. In an act of shear desperation I ran sshgen directly on my linux server and I got the same error, so I don't think its a windows/linux/putty thing anymore ...

I'm running Fedora 17. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds to me like id_rsa.pub is not a readable file. That filename is relative to your .ssh directory. If you're in your home directory, you might mean `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating the key should mean generally putting the in your `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`.

In that case, when [installing a gitolite V3](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/qi.html), I prefer specifying the **full path** of the public key.

```
GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME= gitolite setup -pk "$HOME/.ssh/gitoliteadm.pub"
```

I clear the `$GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME` before calling the setup, in order to make sure the script doesn't mix up that gitolite command with one executed from a web.
You can see an example of a [gitolite instalation script in my project](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh#L18-L23).

Comment: Thanks! This solved it, I guess it wasn't getting the path correctly.